# force:recordEdit Tag UI not working properly in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
<aura:component implements=" lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="con" type="Contact" />
<div class="slds">
<force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="0032800000zZ1fS"/>
    </div>
<div class="slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-horizontal_x-large " >
    <lightning:input label="Name" name="myname" /> 
</div>

<ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
```

[image]

I have used extends="force:slds" in application but no use...Am I missing any thing??? Please Share your inputs on this....

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: Please share the component code as well.

Comment: Possibly related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176683/i-am-trying-to-use-slds-classes-by-extending-app-extends-forceslds-but-the-sl

Comment: Looking at css, I can see that inputs are not using slds classes, but so other ones (uiInput instead of slds-input). I would assume this never worked, even though it's supposed to according to the doc. Did it worked at some point for you ?

Comment: Is your component version 41?

Comment: Yes mine is in version 41

Comment: I just asked about it on the Trailblazer Community here: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F930000000PbJa&fId=0D53A00003JyAQR

Comment: I have just tried this in my dev org and it's look like it's not working outside the one.app container.

Comment: Application 
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
       <c:Recordedit /> 
</aura:application>
Component:
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="con" type="Contact" />
    <force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="0032800000zZ1fS"/>
</aura:component>
so this recordEdit Tag should display all the fields and its values in Lightning based on the record id passed with proper alignment.seems lik  bug.